# Boolean index "&" not working?

Tags: pandas

I am working with a DataFrame `df`:

[image: df.head()]

The following code renders a table with no rows at all:

```
df = df[df['SUMLEV'] == 50 & df['REGION'].isin([1,2])]
```

However, the following code works just fine:

```
df = df[df['SUMLEV'] == 50][df['REGION'].isin([1,2])]
```

What is going wrong with the first line of code?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I was falling victim to order of operations. The following code works:

```
df = df[(df['SUMLEV'] == 50) & (df['REGION'].isin([1,2]))]
```